# How to deal with websites with poor encryption?

Tags: tls, network

I'm trying to access a website over HTTPS. However, it appears that it uses weak encryption: specifically, RC4.
Is there a way to improve the security of my connection to the website? I've been looking into Tor, but unfortunately all exit nodes appear to be blacklisted on the website I'm trying to access.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the SSL Handshake is to determine the cipher to use during transmission.  The cipher suite order can be set server side.  Is RC4 the only algorithm being used?

You can disable the algorithm on the client side by editing the registry.

See [this link](https://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2868725-recommendation-to-disable-rc4.aspx).  MS published an update to disable RC4.  I also believe you can use a tool called [iis crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) to edit your registry.

For firefox, it seems like you can control the SSL ciphers via the about:config page.  Look for security.ssl3

Comment: Do you know of any way to check if other algorithms are used? Firefox only says "Connection encrypted: High-grade encryption (RC4, 128 bit keys)". Also, it'd be nice if you could find some resources which also work on Linux or Mac as well.

Comment: Sorry, always assume Windows :(

Comment: nmap has a plugin to enum the SSL ciphers in use.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Weak_SSL/TSL_Ciphers,_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection_(OWASP-EN-002)#Testing_for_Weak_SSL.2FTSL_Ciphers.2FProtocols.2FKeys_vulnerabilities

Comment: Almost forgot, qualys has an SSL testing tool.  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/  As for linux, I think openssl is used and there should be a conf.  I'm not at a linux box to check tho.  Will update if I find anything